# How can progress bar progress smoothly with 5 minutes counter?

Tags: android

The progress bar has 100 maximum progress and I have 5 minutes counter how I progress my progress bar smoothly with 5 counter maximum

Comment: give progress.setmax(5*60) and for every second setProgress(second)

Comment: I'm using this progress bar in the countdown timer. Progress bar progressing like jumping not smooth...

Comment: you can use setProgress(second,true); true = animate the progress. But this method is available after API 23, below or equal 23 you have to use setProgress(second).

Comment: Got it. Thanks for help